# Schedule task and continue, in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I want my code to schedule a task and immediately proceed to ForeverRunningTaskAsync. This way StopForeverRunningTask executes while ForeverRunningTaskAsync is already in progress for 5 seconds:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith((t) => { StopForeverRunningTask(); }, CancellationToken.None);
  await ForeverRunningTaskAsync();
}
```

Everything's working fine at runtime. However, the compiler warns me that I missed 'await' in Task.Delay call. I don't want to await because ForeverRunningTaskAsync must start immediately, not after the delay. Perhaps, there is a more elegant method of scheduling a task and proceeding to the subsequent code immediately? Or, should I just ignore the warning?

EDIT:
StopForeverRunningTask can actually do anything. From the answers, I see I should have provided more abstract name for it. It does not necessarily stops execution of ForeverRunningTask. It can set some flags, get current state, etc (and even be called multiple times during ForeverRunningTask runtime) so using CancellationToken is not an option. WaitAll approach suggested below answers my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question, why are you using `await` at all? You're not using the result of `ForeverRunningTaskAsync`, nor are you doing anything once it completes, isn't this simply going to start two distinct tasks, one waiting 5 seconds before it does something and the other starting something immediately?

Comment: I just focused on these two (long-running task and a task which somehow controls or examines the flow of the long-running task). Both before and after long-running tasks there are other tasks and long-running task actually has results and so on. I just wanted to make as simple example as possible to leave not-so-important details aside.

Comment: @Alex: You shouldn't use `ContinueWith`. Create a separate `async` method and use `await` instead.

Comment: @StephenCleary I'm afraid I couldn't understand this. Could you expand this a bit?

Comment: @Alex: I explain on my blog why [`ContinueWith` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Instead of using `ContinueWith`, you should have a separate `async` method as such: `private async Task StopAfterDelayAsync() { await Task.Delay(5000); StopForeverRunningTask(); }`, called as such: `var stopper = StopAfterDelayAsync();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its generally not a good idea to ignore that kind of warning. In some contexts it may not have any obvious immediate impact (like in your case) but it leave code fragile to any changes around it.

One of the options that you have is to wait until both tasks are done

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var stopper = Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith((t) => { StopForeverRunningTask(); }, CancellationToken.None);
  var runner = ForeverRunningTaskAsync();
  await Task.WhenAll(stopper, runner);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have a hint in your code of one way to do this instead: `CancellationToken`.

Create a `CancellationToken` that will auto-cancel in 5 seconds:

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
{
    await ForeverRunningTaskAsync(cts.Token);
}
```

Then in your `ForeverRunningTaskAsync()` method do something like:

```
async Task ForeverRunningTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Do stuff, including passing cancellationToken on to anything
        // else that supports it
    }
}
```

If that doesn't quite fit your code or model there are other similar ways to use cancellation tokens, but I would suggest the above is the norm.

Comment: Perhaps, I should have provided better names for methods. In real code, I don't actually need to cancel the long-running method but more like to provide it with more data (or get intermediate results of its execution). I.e. StopForeverRunningTask is actually SomethingWhichDealWithsPropsOfForeverRunningTask. Still, from the look of this question your answer is absolutely correct so I upvoted it. Thanks!

Comment: Please be aware that people here can only answer the question you asked, not the question you *should've* asked. If you don't actually need to *cancel* the other task, you should probably write a question more true to your actual requirements.

Comment: Yes, and I did the required edits now. I just tried to avoid opposite problem where too many details obscure the real question. Finding the right balance between brevity and complexity is a real craft.

Answer (score 1):

Use CancelationTokenSource. After 5 seconds is your task autmatically cancelled.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));

await ForeverRunningTaskAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```